# how to fix $resource:badcfg in my case?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Here is my js code

```
var MYModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myAppServices'])
    .directive('loading',   ['$http', loadingDirective])
    .config(myRouter);

angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Users', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/MY/system/users');
    });

function UsersCtrl($scope, Users) {
    $scope.users = Users.query();
}
```

in my html code just using this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in users">Hello</div>
```

Although I am getting request in my server code at /MY/system/users but the browser is throwing error

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this error documentation: [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24resource/badcfg)

This occurs when angular is expecting an array or an object, and receiving the opposite. `query()` expects an array to be returned from your endpoint, while `get()` expects an object.

Also, you should change your `query()` syntax above to:

```
Users.query().then(function(result){
    $scope.users = result;
});
```

This is because angular is phasing out the automatic handling of promises returned via `$http`.